# Expression engine search using a numbers

Tags: search, custom-fields, fieldtype

I'm having this strange thing when I search for items in EE. Whenever I search for an item having the name "89580.32" this doesn't work. If I add a letter to it, it seems to work. The solution is obvious, just add a letter and that's how I was thinking about solving, though I will forever be wondering why this is as it is.

I have already tried: 
- Changing the database field type to varchar
- Adding a number to make sure it would be indexed (because of it being to short maybe?)
- Deleting the point
...which all didn't work.

Is there anyone out there who can shed some light on this? I assume it's because of it being looked at as a number instead of text?

Update: It's when searching using the search:customer_field inside the EE channel entries tag

Comment: Are the search terms being [logged](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/logs/search_log.html)? [Enable the log](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/search_log_preferences.html) and make a test, please.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear on this, sorry. It's not when using the EE search function, it's when using the search:customer_field inside the EE channel entries tag. I've added this in my question above.

Comment: It looks like a bug, to me. Please, report it.